# Create recursion query

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursion

```
create table #tbl
(
ID int,
[Object] varchar(1),
[Subject] varchar(1)
)

insert into #tbl
select 1, 'A', 'B' union all
select 2, 'A', 'C' union all
select 3, 'A', 'D' union all
select 4, 'B', 'E' union all
select 5, 'B', 'F' union all
select 6, 'D', 'G' union all
select 7, 'D', 'H' union all
select 8, 'G', 'I' union all
select 9, 'G', 'J' union all
select 10, 'I', 'K' union all
select 11, 'I', 'L'

select *
from #tbl
```

I have a relation table with data below. I need to create a query that gives me result below datasets.
When I want to get all the data that A contain I need to go to an atomic value. An atomic value is leaf level.
I need to loop throw datasets several times. A that is 3 times, for B is only 1, for D is two times. What is the best query technics to do?
I am trying to use recursive query using Common Table Expression but I am not getting correct results.

```
 ID OBJECT SUBJECT
  1    A      B
  2    A      C
  3    A      D
  4    B      E
  5    B      F
  6    D      G
  7    D      H
  8    G      I
  9    G      J
  10   I      K
  11   I      L
```

1. A: B (E, F), C, D(G (I (K, L),J), H) > E, F, C, K, L, J, H
2. B: E, F
3. D: G (I (K, L), J), H > K, L, J, H
4. G: I (K, L), J > K, L, J
5. I: K, L

edit

Desired table output:

```
ID OBJECT SUBJECT
 1    A      E
 2    A      F
 3    A      C
 4    A      K
 5    А      L
 6    А      J
 7    А      H
 8    B      E
 9    B      F
 10   D      K
 11   D      L
 12   D      J
 13   D      H
 14   G      K
 15   G      L
 16   G      J
 17   I      K
 18   I      L
```

I try this query:

```
;with cte as 
(
select id, object, subject
from #tbl

union all

select a.id, a.object, a.subject
from #tbl a
join cte b on a.subject=b.object
)
select *
from cte
```

Can anyone help me?

Best Regards

Comment: What's your sqlserver version?

Comment: SQL Server 2012

Comment: How do you want the output to look like?

Comment: A need to be show like E, F, C, I, J, H instead of B, C, D. I want to only I want to complex subject brake to atomic value.

Comment: Can you include what you've tried so far?

Comment: Can you provide the desired output rows with values for each column.

Comment: Are you sure your desired output is correct there?  I would imagine that for `Object = 'A'` you would need to go a level deeper on `I` and return `K` and `L` as the lowest levels?

Comment: sorry, you are right, I am correct to the right output.

Comment: I still don't think your output is correct; you shouldn't have `F` as a top level `Object` in your final results as it isn't one in the source data.

Comment: I think now is everything ok. :D

Comment: I feel like you are messing with us at this point?  `D` drills down to `K, L, J & H` per the logic in your question.

Comment: Sorry again I made this example to illustrate logic of my problem. Thank you for your reply on my question. I hope that now is everything is ok. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of doing with `recursive CTE`(if order isn't necessary)

```
create table #tbl
(
ID int,
[Object] varchar(1),
[Subject] varchar(1)
)

insert into #tbl
select 1, 'A', 'B' union all
select 2, 'A', 'C' union all
select 3, 'A', 'D' union all
select 4, 'B', 'E' union all
select 5, 'B', 'F' union all
select 6, 'D', 'G' union all
select 7, 'D', 'H' union all
select 8, 'G', 'I' union all
select 9, 'G', 'J' union all
select 10, 'I', 'K' union all
select 11, 'I', 'L'

;With
rcte as
(
    -- Anchor member
    select  *, [object] as parent               
    from   #tbl

    union all

    -- Recursive member
    select  c.*, r.parent                 
    from    #tbl c
    inner join rcte r on c.Object = r.Subject
)
Select distinct parent, Subject from rcte x 
where subject not in (Select object from rcte y where x.parent = y.parent)
```

Comment: Thank you for your SQL query.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand your logic (which actually produces different results to your desired output, which I still think is incorrect) and the recursion you need is a bit out of the ordinary in that it requires a self join at the end to remove all rows that aren't the lowest levels in the hierarchy:

```
declare @t table(ID int
                ,[Object] varchar(1)
                ,[Subject] varchar(1)
                );
insert into @t values(1,  'A', 'B'),(2,  'A', 'C'),(3,  'A', 'D'),(4,  'B', 'E'),(5,  'B', 'F'),(6,  'D', 'G'),(7,  'D', 'H'),(8,  'G', 'I'),(9,  'G', 'J'),(10, 'I', 'K'),(11, 'I', 'L');

with r as
(
    select ID
            ,[Object]
            ,[Subject]
            ,0 as Hierarchy
            ,row_number() over (order by ID) as rn
    from @t

    union all

    select t.ID
            ,r.[Object]
            ,t.[Subject]
            ,r.Hierarchy + 1
            ,r.rn
    from r
        join @t as t
            on r.[Subject] = t.[Object]
)
select row_number() over (order by r.[Object], r.rn, r.Hierarchy desc, r.[Subject]) as ID
        ,r.[Object]
        ,r.[Subject]
from r
    left join r r2
        on r.[Subject] = r2.[Object]
where r2.[Object] is null
order by ID;
```

Output:

```
+----+--------+---------+
| ID | Object | Subject |
+----+--------+---------+
|  1 | A      | E       |
|  2 | A      | F       |
|  3 | A      | C       |
|  4 | A      | K       |
|  5 | A      | L       |
|  6 | A      | J       |
|  7 | A      | H       |
|  8 | B      | E       |
|  9 | B      | F       |
| 10 | D      | K       |
| 11 | D      | L       |
| 12 | D      | J       |
| 13 | D      | H       |
| 14 | G      | K       |
| 15 | G      | L       |
| 16 | G      | J       |
| 17 | I      | K       |
| 18 | I      | L       |
+----+--------+---------+
```

Comment: @Дрвосеча  No problem :)  If this was the correct solution for your question do please mark it as such for other users with similar problems.